# Is there a way to map a shared cloud-based network drive (cloud NAS) to Window's native file system?

Tags: windows, cloud, storage, nfs, nas

In summary I'm looking to move to a model where users, working anywhere, have laptops running applications locally but where all files are stored in the cloud.  I'm struggling to find a solution that is comparable to the experience of on-premise NAS.

Pre-CV19 I was using a local network with applications all hosted on local machines and public and private file storage hosted on an on-premise NAS.   With the shift to working form home in CV-19, I moved this to an entirely virtual solution in Azure.   Therefore running Windows Virtual Desktop and with the file storage also in Azure.    From a UX perspective it's exactly the same as it was - I can open up File Explorer and see all folders and files, drag and drop, open from any application, etc.

I want to move to a hybrid model whereby the machines are local again (i.e. not virtual) but because of the need to support WFH the file storage  has to remain in the cloud.  Part of the motivation for this is the cost of Azure (and I know there are cheaper solutions) but it's also about limitations of hardware integration when using the virtual machines.

The vast majority of files need to be accessed by all users, but contain sensitive data so I don't want then synced/mirrored to the local machines.   At least not permanently.

I've looked at SharePoint but the integration seems quite clunky - for example the inability to load files into non-Microsoft applications without additional plugins, workarounds, etc..   OneDrive appears to integrate into the native windows file explorer system perfectly but the sharing and permissions don't appear to be anywhere near as good as those with a standard NAS and using active directory.   For example I understand you would have to invite everybody individually to shared folders, and track and maintain that, rather than being able to rely on a role-based access model.

So my question is whether there's a way to host files in the cloud, that are accessible and shareable as if they were on a NAS, via the standard/native windows file system i.e. I can "open file" in any app and the folder structures and files are visible, and File Explorer can see and search them, in the same way they would be for local machine files, or a networked drive.

One additional key criteria is that I don't want to mirror/sync the file on the local computer - I only ever want it to be stored in the cloud.

I've seen lots of posts recommending SharePoint (doesn't seem to natively integrate), OneDrive (good for one user control, not centralised control), DropBox (again doesn't seem to be "enterprise"), etc.

What I've tried:

SharePoint - this works ok in Microsoft applications, such as Excel, PowerPoint, where you can map "Sites" and through that get access to online locations.   However outside of those Microsoft applications  this isn't possible, so you either need to download files first before you can open them up in non-Microsoft applications, save for a few where there appear to be plugins to mirror the behaviour of the O365 apps.   My understanding is that "View in File Explorer" solution is no longer recommended.  Search seems to be more limited than File Explorer.

OneDrive - this syncs files locally, although I understand you can control this.   The biggest issue appears to be that you need to manage the sharing of every folder - and by inviting every user - rather than being able to use a role-based model.

Many thanks in advance,

Tras